# WordPress | Theme error

Tags: themes

I have placed and previously used WordPress source on my web server everything is up and running including the DB. I even can access the site's admin page but in the theme settings page (Appearance/Themes) I'm getting these errors.

```
Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in /var/www/mysite/wp-includes/theme.php on line 513

Warning: uksort() [function.uksort]: The argument should be an array in /var/www/dialog/wp-admin/themes.php on line 73

Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /var/www/dialog/wp-admin/themes.php on line 94

Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in /var/www/dialog/wp-admin/themes.php on line 150

Warning: natcasesort() [function.natcasesort]: The argument should be an array in /var/www/dialog/wp-admin/themes.php on line 151
```

tried re-uploading the content but didn't work.I'm confused of what causing this error.

Thanks.

Comment: What WP version are you using? [line 513 of wp-includes/theme.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/theme.php#L513) is not PHP code in current version, it's comment

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting your WordPress data, installing a fresh copy of the latest version of WordPress (currently 3.1.1), using a fresh database, and then re-importing your WordPress data.

Answer (score 0):

This error is almost always a permissions error, usually caused by copying files from a Windows box to a Linux box via FTP.  The issue is covered (and resolved) [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/urgent-help-site-stopped-working-array-problem?replies=7), the long and short is this - "You might check your permissions on the wp-content, wp-content/themes and wp-content/plugins folder. If necessary make them 777."

Granted, there's something to be said for keeping WordPress on the latest version, but I'm of the opinion that WordPress updating should be done from inside WordPress - mainly to avoid issues like this.  Once you've got it running, update to the latest version and it should have proper permissions.  Additionally, [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/) will let you know what basic permissions need set for security.